# Cannot clip because "unable to open database file". Do I need to create a geopackage from shapefiles, and if so, how?

Tags: qgis, clip, geopackage

I am working with some shapefiles in QGIS 3.2.1, and I would like to clip one shape file to another, and I am having the following error message.

```
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : '.../Data/landcover/zwe_gc_adg.shp', 'OUTPUT' : 'test', 'OVERLAY' : '.../Data/cyclone_affected_areas/cyclone_affected_districts.shp' }

Could not create layer clipped.gpkg: Creation of data source failed (OGR error: sqlite3_open(clipped.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file)
```

I understand the problem is that I am using shapefiles, and I think I should be using a geopackage, which has layers, but I'm unsure what I need to do (I may just need a good introduction to creating a geopackage from existing shapefiles). Can I then work with the layers of the shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

Geopackage is a database type of format. A single geopackage file can contain multiple layers. When you try to export to a geopackage, some of QGIS's tools assume that the geopackage already exists, and all they need to do is add a new layer to it. If the geopackage doesn't exist, you get an error message like "unable to open database file." It seems that the `clip` tool is one of those tools that can't create a geopackage file. I expect that eventually, all of QGIS's tools will be able to create new geopackages, and this issue will be resolved. Geopackage is a rather underutilized file format at the moment, though.

As a workaround, try outputting to the default [temporary layer]. Then export the temporary layer as a geopackage. When you export a layer to geopackage that doesn't exist yet, QGIS creates the geopackage for you.

Comment: Or try another file format for the result, like geojson or shp.